# Copy and paste data from the next Excel sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm a complete beginner with VBA and I looked at other topics but couldn't really find an answer (at least that I could understand).

Basically I have Excel workbooks for different subjects during a research project.

I want to copy past some data from the subjects workbook and past it to a master Workbook. This code does it for one subject.

It open the selected workbook, copy past what is needed in the right place then close it then open the next condition etc.

I'd like to find a way to tell it to open the next workbook (ie: Patient1GlobalP.xlsm becomes Patient2GlobalP.xlsm, then 3 then 4...) and do the same but copy to the next cell (the range that is copied stay the same but `Range("C2").Select` becomes `Range("D2").Select` for the copy destination, C1509 becomes D1509 and C3016 becomes D3016 then E then F...). I can do it by hand but there has to be a more elegant solution like some kind of offset.

```
Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B1:B1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle X").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("C1:C1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle Y").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("C1:C1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle Z").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("N1:N1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee X").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("O1:O1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee Y").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("P1:P1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee Z").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("I1:I1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip X").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("J1:J1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip Y").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1GlobalP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("J1:J1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip Z").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\hugo\Desktop\data\Patient1LocalP.xlsx"
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B1:B1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle X").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("C1:C1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle Y").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("C1:C1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle Z").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("N1:N1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee X").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("O1:O1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee Y").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("P1:P1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee Z").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("I1:I1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip X").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("J1:J1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip Y").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    Range("J1:J1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip Z").Select
    Range("C1509").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1LocalP.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\hugo\Desktop\data\Patient1Nopert.xlsx"
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B1:B1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle X").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("C1:C1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle Y").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("C1:C1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ankle Z").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("N1:N1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee X").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("O1:O1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee Y").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("P1:P1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Knee Z").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("I1:I1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip X").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("J1:J1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip Y").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    Range("J1:J1505").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("master.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Hip Z").Select
    Range("C3016").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("Patient1Nopert.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
```

Comment: Declare a variable to track the next open row. Loop through the workbooks. Paste starting with the open row and increment the open row by the number of rows pasted.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know the term "loop through" so I searched for that and it helped. I don't think there is a way to loop specifically for Patient1GlobalP then 2 then 3 if all files are in the same folder so I guess the best way to do it is to put each condition in a different folder and then loop through that ?

Comment: You could loop through all the workbooks, then test the workbook name to see if it is one that should be appended. Alternatively you could create the list of workbook names you'd like to append using a loop, then do your copy and paste operation for each name in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const SRC_FLDR As String = "C:\something\myfiles\"

    Dim wbM As Workbook, wbS As Workbook, shtS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, colOff As Long

    Set wbM = Workbooks("master.xlsx")

    colOff = 0 'paste position offset

    For i = 1 To 10 'eg
        Set wbS = Workbooks.Open(SRC_FLDR & "Patient" & i & "GlobalP.xlsm")
        Set shtS = wbS.Sheets(1)

        'copy ranges to specific positions on Master sheets
        '  offset changes each time through the loop
        'NOTE: no need to use Activate/Select here
        shtS.Range("B1:B1505").Copy wbS.Sheets("Ankle X").Range("C2").Offset(0, colOff)
        shtS.Range("C1:C1505").Copy wbS.Sheets("Ankle Y").Range("C2").Offset(0, colOff)
        shtS.Range("C1:C1505").Copy wbS.Sheets("Ankle Z").Range("C2").Offset(0, colOff)
        'etc...
        'etc...

        wbS.Close savechanges:=False
        colOff = colOff + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```